# Antlr4 - Grammar Parsing a log file

Tags: java, parsing, logging, antlr4

I am trying to parse log file entries.

**LogGram.g4**

```
grammar LogGram;

logs: log* ;

log : dateformat Identifier '[' className ']' '(' thread ')'
;

thread : Letter+ SPECIAL* LetterOrDigit+
   ;

className : Identifier ('.' Identifier)* ;

dateformat : DATE TMSTAMP ;    

Identifier : Letter LetterOrDigit* ;

Letter : [a-zA-Z$_] ;

LetterOrDigit : [a-zA-Z0-9$_];

SPECIAL : [-@#,;:'"/] ;

DATE : DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT '-' DIGIT DIGIT '-' DIGIT DIGIT ;

TMSTAMP : DIGIT DIGIT ':' DIGIT DIGIT ':' DIGIT DIGIT ',' DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT         
 ;

DIGIT : [0-9] ;

WS : [ \t\r\n\u000C]+ -> skip;
```

**Server.log**

```
2017-08-10 12:50:56,081 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-32)
```

**Console Output while parsing and printing it**

```
line 1:53 mismatched input 'default' expecting Letter
2017-08-10 12:50:56,081 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (defaulttask-32)
```

Why is the mismatch line appearing before printing output?

Comment: Your grammar is generally wrong. For example, lexer rule `Letter` will never match, because every letter is also an `Identifier`. Remember, that parser cannot dictate lexer how to split input into tokens. *First* lexer does its work, only then the parser sees the resulting token stream. Since in logfiles there are no well-defined tokens and they depend on context, you probably need to ditch parser completely and use lexer grammar with modes.

Comment: @doublep Thanks for suggestions. I will go through the ANTLR4 reference book to learn more about lexer grammar.

Comment: Though maybe it's better to do the other way around and write a lexer that matches single characters and move rules like `identifier` to the parser level. Hard to say.

Answer (score 1):

I am not antlr expert. Just an idea

```
SPECIAL : [-@#,;:'"/] ;
```

uses `-` char which is used to define ranges
could you try another way

```
HYPHEN : '-';
SPECIAL : [@#,;:'"/] | HYPHEN ;
```